# Partitions of $n$: proving $p(n+2)+ p(n) \geq 2p(n+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> For $n \geq 2$ give an alternative description of $p(n) - p(n-1)$ as the number of partitions of $n$ which have a certain property.

I have done that part, it is fine. I have not included it here as I am not accustomed with LaTeX but can put it up if wanted. But then it says

> Hence or otherwise prove $p(n+2)+ p(n) \geq 2p(n+1)$.

This is the part I do not know how to do. Any help appreciated thank you

Comment: Give $n$, what does $p(n)$ return?

Comment: p(n) is the number of partitions of n

Comment: @moony So $p(n)-p(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of n that do not have $1$ in their sum.. correct?

Comment: sorry, p(n) - p(n-1) is the number of partition with smallest part = 2

Comment: @moony How is that different from what I said? :P

Comment: oops sorry, i have exams and my head does not seem to want to follow any logical train of thought!

Comment: @moony No pb :) Try the hint of Sharkos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint*: The stated inequality is equivalent to
$$p(n+2)-p(n+1)\ge p(n+1)-p(n)$$

Comment: right ok, can you give me any more than that, should i equate them?

Comment: What did you just show in the previous part of the question?

Comment: I showed that p(n) - p(n-1) represents the number of partitions whose smallest part is 2.

Comment: ... Can you not see how that relates to the rearranged statement I wrote down?

Comment: Nope sorry, I can't think straight at the moment, I'v been having exams all week

Comment: Well if $f(n)=p(n)-p(n-1)$ then the rearranged statement I wrote down is $f(n+2)\ge f(n+1)$.

Comment: ok thank you, sorry I get it now

Comment: @Sharkos I understand what there is to show; that the number of partitions of n with smallest part 2 increases with n. But I don't understand how to prove it from your post/comments: is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: I didn't say anything about that part, I left it for the OP to solve. It's pretty similar to the reason $p(n)$ itself increases, and not at all hard to show. I'll leave it to you unless you want a hint.

Comment: @Sharkos See my answer if you have some time :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference $p(n)-p(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ that do not contain 1/with smallest part (wsp) 2 -- also denoted $p(2,n)$, where $p(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the intermediate function. Using Sharkos's hint, we understand that we aim to prove that $p(2,n)$ is increasing. One way to prove this is to find an injection that, to any partition of $n$ wsp 2, assigns a partition of $n+1$ wsp 2.

Clearly, by adding 1 to any such partition of $n$, we obtain a partition of $n+1$. But doing so by simply adding "+1" to the sum would not make it a valid partition of $n+1$ wsp 2 (the smallest part would be 1).

Instead, consider adding 1 to any of the existing addends of any given partition $P$ of $n$ wsp 2. Our goal is to ensure that we would not obtain the same partition of $n+1$ twice (since it wouldn't be an injection then), and this can be achieved by chosing to systematically add 1 to the *greatest* element of $P$.

Doing so, we obtain the desired injection, and therefore we prove that there are at least as many partitions of $n+1$ than of $n$ wsp 2.

Comment: @Sharkos Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.